# ROR + Failed to Install Gem via Bundler

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

Error occured while deploying sample app to Heroku.

Rails Version - 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3

But getting strange issue of Bundler

[image]

Error Console : Windows CMD Prompt - Here console mentioned about ruby 2 but 1.9.3 is installed version of my machine.

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       New app detected loading default bundler cache
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
       troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
       /tmp/build_07f8cd6f-1940-4d6a-9073-77757dd85710/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/rub
y/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme http does not accept regi
stry part: :443 (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
       from /tmp/build_07f8cd6f-1940-4d6a-9073-77757dd85710/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/li
b/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb:84:in `initialize'
       from /tmp/build_07f8cd6f-1940-4d6a-9073-77757dd85710/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/li
b/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:214:in `new'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https:/rubygems.org'    
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'    
gem 'ruby', '1.9.3'   # Addition of ruby verstion for Heroku    
gem 'pg'    
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end    
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Not getting the way to resolve it.

Comment: This is the end of a stack trace, but the actual error that you're getting is at the beginning of the stack trace. Could you copy and paste the entire stack trace? Also, copy and pasting rather than posting a screenshot ensures that your error message is text that is searchable. This can help other people searching for the same error.

Comment: This is not sufficient info. to help you. Instead of a screen-cap, could you please paste the entire stack-trace formatted around code-tags?

Comment: Done as per suggestion. Plz have a look

Comment: post your Gemfile, there seems to be a malformed url in there.

Comment: Interesting -1 for problem. Great Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gemfile is incorrect. It should include Ruby in the following way:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"
# ...
```

as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: No success. 
D:\Development\SampleApp>bundle install
Fetching source index from https:/rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https:/rubygems.org/

D:\Development\SampleApp>bundle install
Fetching source index from http:/rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from http:/rubygems.org/

Comment: you are missing a second slash before rubygems.org, see answer above.